# You say [television], I say [tv]. Let's merge them

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

While answering a MSE question about [where to post TV related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298678/351462), I was surprised to learn that SO has separate tags for [tv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tv) (*325 questions*) and [television](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/television) (*34 questions*)

Considering [TV is just an abbreviation for Television](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television), I see no reason not to merge the two tags.

[image: Small TV]

Comment: Is it even needed? Seems irrelevant to most questions if you just consider it a form of "display". Bit more interesting is why there  are samsung-smart-tv and lg tags... Looks like they could use a good look-through and potential clean up.

Comment: I don't see many cases where it's used for *Questions directly relating to the development of TV apps, TV web apps, second screen experiences, etc.*... Most seem to just use it to indicate a TV is plugged in somewhere and others are off-topic hardware problems... Quite a mess.

Comment: *let's call the whole thing off* - literally.

Comment: @jonclements how is this different than a tag like [tag:chess]? If someone is developing an app for tv, a tag for categorizing such questions might be useful. Bad usage by some users shouldn't doom a useful tag

Comment: Questions about Android TV should be retagged with [tag:android-tv]